# Show a sequence converges (Probably using Cauchy's sequence Thm)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

This demand is a part of a proof. It must be easy, I'm just failing showing it rigorously.

Let: $\left| {x_{n+1} -x_n} \right| < {1\over 2^n}$

We want to prove it's a Cauchy's sequence:

Without the lose of generality, Let us assume $m>n$:

$$\left| {{x_m} - {x_n}} \right| = \left| {{x_m} - {x_{m - 1}} + {x_{m - 1}} - {x_{m - 2}} + ... + {x_{n + 1}} - {x_n}} \right| \le \left| {{x_m} - {x_{m - 1}}} \right| + ... + \left| {{x_{n + 1}} - {x_n}} \right| \le \frac{1}{{{2^m}}} + ... + \frac{1}{{{2^n}}}$$

I feel like I'm on the right path. Can you help from here?

Comment: Can you prove it is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Hmm.. I think I am allowed to use it, But if there's a more fundamental way, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: I meant, have you tried to prove it's a Cauchy sequence? :-)

Comment: Oh ok, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Okay. Let us know how it goes. By the way, you can't assume there's a limit $L$ in the proof.

Comment: @NotMe, please have a look at my edition.

Comment: TheNumber23 has already answered, but you can also use $$\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^m}\le \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}\le \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$, and $n$ can be chosen so that $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. Since the series $\sum_{k\geq 0}2^{-k}$ converges, the tail must go to zero. So there exists $N$ such that $$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}2^{-k}<\epsilon$$. 
Let $n>m\geq N$. Then do what you have done.

Comment: what about the parity of $m,n$. Should I refer it in my proof? Does it affect my proof?

Comment: @SuperStamp No the parity doesn't make an difference.